# MYSQL on delete cascade example

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out how to use `on delete cascade` in my example.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `login` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`login`),
  UNIQUE KEY `login` (`login`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Surname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Birthday` date NOT NULL,
  `Adres` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Telephone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `login` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `login` (`login`),
  CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`login`) REFERENCES `users` (`login`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

One table stores informations about employee and if he has account(login) there is another table with logins and passwords.

My goals:

1. Not every employee needs to have user account(that means - unique record in `Users` table) so `Employees.Login` shouldn't be restricted with NOT NULL.
2. I want possiblity to add new user in `Users` and then assign it to some employee.
3. When I delete employee, related unique user is also deleted(if he had one).

First two are already done. I don't know how to make **3** happen now.

Answer (score 1):

You've put the CONSTRAINT in the wrong CREATE TABLE statement. It goes on the referencing table, which is `"users"`, because that's the table you want to automatically delete from when a row in the other table is deleted.

You want to put a nullable `"ID"` in the `"users"` table, which is unique and a foreign key to `"employees"`.

Comment: how then `Employees.Login` should be defined?

Comment: It shouldn't. The Employees table doesn't need to know about logins. Get rid of that column in Employees.

Comment: I have posted answer how it works now. However I would like to know how can I now display every row from `employees` table with additional column with information wherever employee has account or not?

Comment: You need to do a left join using the ID columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query :

```
        CREATE TABLE `users` (
      `login` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`login`),
      UNIQUE KEY `login` (`login`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


    CREATE TABLE `employees` (
      `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `Surname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `Birthday` date NOT NULL,
      `Adres` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `Telephone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `login` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
      UNIQUE KEY `login` (`login`),
      CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`login`) REFERENCES `users` (`login`)  ON DELETE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: this will do the opposite of what I want. It will delete coressponding `Employee` when I delete `User` row, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Based on suggestion from **Hammerite** now my tables definion looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Surname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Birthday` date NOT NULL,
  `Adres` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Telephone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `login` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`login`),
  UNIQUE KEY `login` (`login`),
  UNIQUE KEY `employee_id` (`employee_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id`) REFERENCES `employees` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

1. I have deleted `login` column from `employees` table
2. I have created another column `employee_id` in `User` table. It's unique foreign key and cannot be null since I dont want user accounts that are not used by anybody.

Now If I do this:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES('login123','password',2);
```

then this row will be deleted after I do this:

```
DELETE FROM employees WHERE id=2;
```

I was sure that I need to make some reference in `employees` table to `users` table, thats why I didn't think about solution like this.

THANKS!